# How to dump SSHD process and search for strings

Tags: sshd

Symantec has disclosed details on an SSHD backdoor and suggests to dump the SSHD process and search for some particular strings.

**NOTE:** Background here: [Symantec report on Linux Back Door](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/linux-back-door-uses-covert-communication-protocol)

I have no idea how to perform the steps to dump the SSHD process and search the dump. Hoping someone can describe the steps one would follow to do this on a Linux system such as Fedora.

Answer (score 2):

First get the process id for sshd, e.g. with

```
ps eax | grep sshd | fgrep -v grep | cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

Then use that as pid to look at the process map:

```
cat /proc/<pid_you_found>/maps
```

Next connect with `gdb` to the memory range you are interested in and dump (to file)

```
gdb --pid pid_you_found
(gdb) dump memory file_name startaddr endaddr
```

You can then analyse the strings in file_name.

(I use a python script to the `gdb` part repeatedly on all the memory ranges and write the output to one file.)

Comment: how to use those symbols from the `/proc/<pid_you_found>/maps` file? for a line starting `7ffd49ddc000-7ffd49dde000 r-xp`,  I try `dump memory file_name  7ffd49ddc000 7ffd49dde00` and get `(gdb) Invalid number "7ffd49ddc000".`